# Replace HTML in response using Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I want to do something as simple as changing a color code in the response of an HTTP request, but I can't seem to figure it out. Basically, when a certain website loads, The background is set with the color code "#db4437" and I'd like to have it always be changed to "#09C3FF" when the website loads.

I found this code for Fiddlerscript in the Fiddler guides, but it doesn't seem to really do anything at all

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.bayden.com") && 
oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type","text/html")){
oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
oSession.utilReplaceInResponse('<b>','<u>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example from Telerik documentation works for me:

Remove all DIV tags (and content inside the DIV tag)

```
// If content-type is HTML, then remove all DIV tags
if (oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "html")){
  // Remove any compression or chunking
  oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
  var oBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.responseBodyBytes);

  // Replace all instances of the DIV tag with an empty string
  var oRegEx = /<div[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div>/gi;
  oBody = oBody.replace(oRegEx, "");

  // Set the response body to the div-less string
  oSession.utilSetResponseBody(oBody); 
}
```